# how to handle unnecessary width of select on first focus in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-11

I got trouble with IE11
select with extra width on first time focus.
[image: bug screenshot]

code is-

```
<select id="blipType" class="btn-sm fa-select" style="margin-bottom: 3px;">
                        <option value="Public" selected="selected">
                            &#xf09c;&nbsp;Public
                        </option>
                        <option value="MyCompany">
                            &#xf023;&nbsp;Private
                        </option>
                    </select>
```

how i can handle this issue?

Comment: Can you share your code along with the screenshot?

Comment: Don't you think you have missed to ask question?